# How to construct a principal clause?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, subjects, predicate, sentence

How can I construct a perfect sentence? Both, principal and subordinate clause has a subject and a predicate. How can I be sure that the sentence I formed is a principal clause?

For e.g. *I am very tired*

Is this a principal clause? Or should I say, *I am very tired, today.*

What are the main elements of a principal clause that can confirm that my sentence is a principal clause?

Comment: A main clause is not dependent on some other element in the sentence. In other words, it is not embedded as a dependent within some larger clause. Generally, a main clause can stand alone as a sentence.

Comment: On a side note: you should be using "principle", not "principal". A principal is the head of an elementary school or high school (in the US). In other words, a school below the university or college level. A common aid to keeping the usage straight is to remember that "the principal is your pal".

Answer (score 1):

If a sentence only has one clause, then that clause is the principle clause.

The main property of a principle clause is that it is not subordinate to another clause. If there is only one clause, this condition is satisfied trivially.